# Broken packages/dependancies for telegram

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install telegram using

```
sudo apt install telegram-desktop
```

and getting the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 telegram-desktop : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-9-5
                    Recommends: fonts-open-sans but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how to fix this?

Edited: no instructions, I am just trying to download it from an official ubuntu repository.

```
sudo apt update:
```

No packages require updating to newer versions.

Comment: Please add to your question above: 1) A link to the instructions you were following, and 2) The complete output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: As a workaround you could just install the snap package with "sudo snap install telegram-desktop".

Comment: yes, I know, but why does it not work this way? I want an official and tested version by ubuntu community

Comment: It doesn't work because you have held broken packages. That's why we need to see the complete output of `sudo apt update` -- your summary is insufficient. It will tell us which non-Ubuntu sources (or wrong-version Ubuntu sources) that you have unwisely added. Then we will tell you to start removing those sources, and uninstalling all packages from those sources. At some point, you will remove the incompatible package that introduced the *version conflict* (held broken packages) that prevents apt from working. Then apt will begin working again.